# Visual Studio 2013 not recognizing reference to my new Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, model, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on an ASP.Net application. For one part of this, I have particular models stored in their own folder:

[image: Models]

I have a reference to my `Models/Default/` folder in one of my CustomControls: `using Project.Models.Default`; However, when I try to make a reference in my CustomControl `YearsOfService` to my default Model of `Years_Of_Service`, Visual Studio (2013) is not picking up either my `Years_Of_Service` or `Years_Of_Service_Data` model with my `Models/Default/` folder:

[image: Code2]

Anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

**EDIT**:

**Years_Of_Service.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace PROJECT.Models
{
    public class YearsOfService
    {
        public string Year { get; set; }
        public decimal ServiceCredited { get; set; }
        public decimal Salary { get; set; }
        public string CoveredEmployer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Years_Of_Service_Data.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace PROJECT.Models
{
    public class YearsOfServiceData
    {
        public List<YearsOfService> YearsOfService { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the content of those files? Are the classes inside in the correct namespace (i.e. XXXX.Models.Default)?

Comment: Show us the contents of `Years_Of_Service.cs` to give us a clue!

Comment: Is this a Web Application project or a Web Site project?

Comment: @Belogix, contents added above in edit. @@DavidG, I think you may be right but I'm not fully sure what to change. Over the course of a few attempted fixes I've moved the models from /Models/ & /Models/Default/ as well as changed the name a time or 2. @@@Erik, this is a Web App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have:

```
namespace PROJECT.Models
```

But this should also contain `Default` like this:

```
namespace PROJECT.Models.Default
```

So, it should end up like this:

```
namespace PROJECT.Models.Default
{
    public class YearsOfServiceData
    {
        public List<YearsOfService> YearsOfService { get; set; }
    }  
}
```

Finally, you may want to keep your file names and class names the same otherwise it can get very confusing! So, stick with either **Years_Of_Service_Data** or **YearsOfServiceData** in both file and class name.

Comment: Thanks for the help Belogix. The differences I think stem from me renaming "YearsOfServiceData" for example to "Years_Of_Service_Data", but VS2013 did not change all of my references for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

The classes contained in those files are just in the wrong namespace. Specify the correct one like this:

```
namespace XXXX.Models.Default 
{
    public class YearsOfService
    {
        //Snip
    }
}
```

Alternatively, refer to them with their namespace as `XXXX.Models.YearsOfService`